# How can I return a subset of a Vec?

Tags: vector, rust, subset, slice, lifetime

I'm trying to avoid copying data as the memory use of this program has to be kept low.

I've seen that you can do something like:

```
fn subset<'a>(csv: &Vec<&'a Vec<bool>>, indices: &Vec<usize>) -> Vec<&'a Vec<bool>> {
    indices.iter().map(|&i| &csv[i]).collect();
}
```

But my data source is actually a `&Vec<Vec<bool>>` not a `&Vec<&Vec<bool>>` and `'a` on it's own doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `'a` is simply misplaced.

A lifetime is always used in conjunction with a reference, so if you have a `&Vec<Vec<bool>>` then the lifetime `'a` comes right after the `&`. You do not need, and should not, sprinkle `&` nilly-willy as there is a very clear difference between something that you own (`i32`) and something you refer to (`&i32`).

Thus, the correct version of your function simply is:

```
fn subset<'a>(csv: &'a Vec<Vec<bool>>, indices: &Vec<usize>) -> Vec<&'a Vec<bool>> {
    indices.iter().map(|&i|&csv[i]).collect()
}
```

*Note: I removed the semi-colon after `collect`, as you want to return the value of that expression.*

And we can use this function:

```
fn main() {
    let vec = vec!(
        vec!(false, false, false),
        vec!(false, false, true ),
        vec!(false, true , true ),
        vec!(false, true , false),
        vec!(true , true , false),
        vec!(true , true , true ),
        vec!(true , false, true ),
        vec!(true , false, false)
    );

    let indices = vec!(1, 3, 5, 7);

    let sub = subset(&vec, &indices);

    println!("{:?}", sub);
}
```

Which [produces](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e4442c648fd13ecd9afe&version=stable):

```
[[false, false, true], [false, true, false], [true, true, true], [true, false, false]]
```